# remote: Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /home/kovair/git_home/OmnibusAdapterListener/Log4perl/lib/Log/Log4perl/Appender.pm line 164

Tags: git, perl

Whenever I am doing push in Git its shows me success. This are the messages that are displayed==>

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 260 bytes | 86.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /home/kovair/git_home/OmnibusAdapterListener/Log4perl/lib/Log/Log4perl/Appender.pm line 164.
To ssh://192.168.12.232/~/git_home/.git
8a760af..d54ede4  master -> master

Success (10453 ms @ 5/20/2021 1:55:36 PM)
```

remote: Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /home/kovair/git_home/OmnibusAdapterListener/Log4perl/lib/Log/Log4perl/Appender.pm line 164.

Lines of code related to this message :

```
                #not defined, the normal case
        if (! defined $self->{warp_message} ){
                #join any message elements
            $p->{message} = 
                join($Log::Log4perl::JOIN_MSG_ARRAY_CHAR, 
                 @{$p->{message}}  <== line mentioned in message 164 
                     ) if ref $p->{message} eq "ARRAY";
```

Now the problem is after successful push the pushed files are not coming in the server repo.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Am I doing push in a wrong way or the problem is due to the code.

Comment: *"git.exe"* Is this on Windows (since you are using `git.exe` and not just `git`) ?

Comment: The server has an old version of Log4perl.  Newer versions (since [this commit](https://github.com/mschilli/log4perl/commit/3bfef78c7f0138b84a953bbe631cf303c24dda03) in 2012) show a stack trace when there is an `undef` in the array referenced by `$p->{messages}`. See [Log4perl issue #15](https://github.com/mschilli/log4perl/issues/15).

Comment: @HåkonHægland my git server is in linux and I am pushing data from windows with git client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Update that part according to your version.